# How to dynamically set group access in apache2 configuration

Tags: authentication, apache2, trac

I have an apache configuration containing the following directives. It is for a trac environment with multiple projects, each containing a different set of users that are allowed access.

I want to use a wildcard to allow only a defined group access to this environment, how can this be done? Currently my config allowes all users:

```
<LocationMatch "/private/[^/]+/login">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Trac"
        AuthUserFile /home/auth/private.access.user
        Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

But I would like it to read something like:

```
<LocationMatch "/private/[^/]+/login">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Trac"
        AuthUserFile /home/auth/private.access.user
        Require Group [^/]
</LocationMatch>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Trac, I find it much easier to allow access to everybody in the Apache config and then use Trac's account manager plugin (http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) to control access to each project's Trac instance.  Revoke all permissions from the 'anonymous' user, and users from group2 won't be able to do anything with group1's Trac instance except see an error page and be prompted to login.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following...

```
<LocationMatch "/private/[^/]+/login">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Trac"
        AuthUserFile /home/auth/private.access.user
        AuthGroupFile /home/auth/private.access.groups
        Require Group group1 group2
</LocationMatch>
```

Where the group file /home/auth/private.access.groups is just a simple text (ascii) file, for example it could look like this:

```
group1: john barry
group2: frank jeremy
```

I'm not sure it Regular Expressions are possible in Require Group directive (I doubt they are), I always name particular names of groups listed in the group authentication file.

Comment: Yes, but then a member from group2 will be able to access the trac environment for group1, or am I mistaken here?

Comment: so you want more granularity in access control...not sure if it is doable in apache, but for bigger granularity you could use something like this http://sumoam.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: Thank you, I checked sumoam, it is not usable for what I asked here, but I appreciate you trying to hand me a solution.